# Handle TransferText Errors

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba, runtime-error

I have an **Access-2007** application, I use Visual Basic to export/import tables from text file.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "MySpec", "Table1", "c:\table1.txt", True

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "MypSpec", "Table1", "c:\table1.txt", True
```

I want to **trap all errors** that this method can raise. I want to have the list of this method's error numbers, I searched on MSDN but I didn't find any thing.

Also I want to prevent access from creating ***ImportErrors*** table if the import fails.

Any idea ?

Comment: The built in `TransferText` was intended to be as simple as possible so that basic user's could import data into access, hence why the ability to interrogate it is limited. Aside from Remou's suggestion you could parse the file yourself via VBA, this would allow you to test and validate your data before insert, however as you mentioned your app is large and it won't be worth the re-write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SQL if you want to pre-test the data.

Use a schema.ini file and a straight import to MS Access. A schema.ini file is comparable to a specification.

```
[imp.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=FixedLength
Col1=ID  Char Width 8
Col2=AName  Char Width 10
Col3=Mark Char Width 2
```

SQL

```
SELECT * INTO Imp FROM [Text;DATABASE=Z:\docs].[imp.txt]
```

In VBA:

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDB

sSQL = "SELECT * INTO Imp FROM [Text;DATABASE=Z:\docs].[imp.txt]"
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

References: 
[Errors Collection (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834805.aspx)
[Error Object (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835711.aspx)
[Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but I actually prefer using TransferText (My app is very huge, I cant change now). What about prevent access from creating ImportErrors table if the import fails?

Comment: "I don't believe there's any way to prevent Access from creating it." -- Douglas Steele, Access MVP. You should be able to find the table and delete it.

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems more stable, I'll try to use it in next apps. Thanks

Comment: Nice solution, but where do you store this `shema.ini` ? The SQL sample does not seem to explicitely refer to it. Does it have to be in the same folder as the CSV ?

Comment: @iDevlop Yes, it has to be in the same folder as far as I recall.