# MSAccess Link CSV file as a table on startup

Tags: ms-access, csv, import

I struggle with a problem with linked tables to csv file.
I did the attach by VBA code like this :

```
With CurrentDb
  Dim ts As DAO.TableDef
  Set ts = .CreateTableDef("cli")
  ts.SourceTableName = "CLI1.csv"
  ts.Connect = "Text;DSN=CLI1 Spec;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=C:\Users\user1\Desktop"
  .TableDefs.Append ts
  .TableDefs.Refresh
End With
```

When this is called manually, the table is correctly attached.
When this is called automatically inside the autoexec macro, I get an error 3625 saying that the text file specification "CLI1 Spec" does not exist... throught it does !

Maybe it is because when running an autoexec macro the context is not fully initialized... but what can I do to have it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
With CurrentDb
  Dim ts As DAO.TableDef
  Set ts = .CreateTableDef("cli")
  ts.SourceTableName = "CLI1.csv"
  ts.Connect = "Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=C:\Users\user1\Desktop"
  .TableDefs.Append ts
  .TableDefs.Refresh
End With
```

If that does not suit, it is not too difficult to use a schema.ini file and sql, for example: [Handle TransferText Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730093/handle-transfertext-errors/14730415#14730415)

Comment: I don"t think that would suit because the specification is not given. And I'd prefer not to create a schema file because the import has been working in a production environment for years. I just want to put the path ofthe csv in an ini file and attach it on the application startup.

Comment: On the other hand it's far more clean and transparent using system.ini. Moreover it seems to work even inside autoexec macro